# Вы как хотите, а я ухожу

Tags: синтаксис

Мне необходимо определить, чем является выделенный фрагмент и я в тупике. Если не ошибаюсь, можно было бы добавить "*Вы поступайте как хотите, а я*...". Я задаю вопрос "*поступайте каким образом?*" и прихожу к какой-то конструкции образа действия (но не уверена, что такое существует). Или это какая-то сравнительная конструкция? Исправьте меня, пожалуйста!

*Вы **как хотите**, а я ухожу.*

Comment: Слово "поступаите" а русском языке нет. Исправьте, пожалуйста, на "поступаете" или "поступайте" - в зависимости от смысла.

Comment: @IrinaGL: у меня не русские буквы на notebook. в программе, где я печатаю, нет экстра значков. я имела в виду краткое и.

Comment: Нет проблем, поправила. А то плохо воспринимается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы как хотите, а я ухожу.

Вы (поступайте) как хотите (=по-своему), а я ухожу.

**Это сложносочиненное предложение**, союз А имеет значение сопоставления. Первое предложение неполное (эллиптическое), оборот "как хотите" **является устойчивым и имеет значение одного слова (по-своему).**

Вопрос задается верно: вы поступайте (как?) – по-своему (как хотите), это **обстоятельство образа действия**.

Answer (score 1):

```
 необходимо определить, чем является выделенный фрагмент
```

Вы как хотите, а я ухожу.- Видимо, подразумевается, что Вы должны сказать "является фразеологизмом".Это цельные по смыслу выражения, которые не следует путать с придаточными сравнительными предложениями.

У Розенталя: Не разделяются запятой выражения с глаголом хотеть, образующие цельные по смыслу выражения: пиши как хочешь,приходи когда хочешь, распоряжайтесь как хотите. А у Вас "поступайте как хотите" - тот же случай. Фразеологизм со значением "по-своему"

Answer (score 0):

Это точно не сравнительная конструкция, это наречное значение. 
Глагол, как вы верно заметили, опущен.

Вы [можете поступать], как хотите, а я ухожу.
Желательная пунктуация тут:

**Вы -- как хотите, а я ухожу.**

В полном виде перед "как" возможна запятая, но в стянутом её нет, просто некуда ставить.